# System.NullReferenceException thrown despite of properly initialised object

Tags: c#, exception, object

I'm trying to write an inventory system for an RPG. I have custom type called 'Item', and a class called 'Bag'. An item can be put into a bag with this function:

```
public Item aw = new Item();
public void PutIn(Item aw)
{
    Contents[Index]=aw;
    Index++;        
}
```

When I call the function with

```
Bag.PutIn(someItem);
```

in the main code it throws a System.NullReferenceException.
By researching the issue I found out that this is usually caused by improperly initialised objects, but in this case I *did* initialise the object with Item aw = new Item();. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Contents[Index]=aw; is throwing the System.NullReferenceException. How do you initialize Contents?

Comment: We need to see more of your code, what you've included is not enough.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its not the Item object that is not initialized. You probably didn't initialize "Contents" array.